# How can I get a "flat" output of data from a parent / child table with LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have two tables. The `Word` table contains a list of words and then the `WordForm` table contains a list of parts of speech for each word.

```
public class Word
{
    public Word()
    {
        CategoryId = 1;
        WordForms = new System.Collections.Generic.List<WordForm>();
    }
    public string WordId { get; set; } // WordId (Primary key) (length: 20)
    public int CategoryId { get; set; } // CategoryId
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<WordForm> WordForms { get; set; } // WordForm.FK_WordFormWord
    public virtual WordCategory WordCategory { get; set; } // FK_WordWordCategory

}

public class WordForm
{
    public string WordFormId { get; set; } // WordFormId (Primary key) (length: 20)
    public string WordId { get; set; } // WordId (length: 20)
    public int PosId { get; set; } // PosId
    public string Definition { get; set; } // Definition
    public virtual Pos Pos { get; set; } // FK_WordFormPos
    public virtual Word Word { get; set; } // FK_WordFormWord
}
```

I tried joining these two tables like this:

```
var word = db.Words
            .Include(wf => wf.WordForms)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

This gives me an output in object form.

How can I get to see what is in the tables so that I have returned to me data like this where each row has all of these columns:

```
WordId  CategoryId   WordFormId  PosId   Definition
WordId  CategoryId   WordFormId  PosId   Definition
WordId  CategoryId   WordFormId  PosId   Definition
WordId  CategoryId   WordFormId  PosId   Definition
```

Comment: Where do you need to place your data ultimately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany` to flatten the output:

```
 var words = db.Words
               .Include(wf => wf.WordForms)
               .SelectMany(w => w.WordForms.Select(wf => new
               {
                   WordId = w.WordId,
                   CategoryId = w.CategoryId,
                   WordFormId = wf.WordFormId,
                   PosId = wf.PosId,
                   Definition = wf.Definition
               }));
```

If you want the result only for the first `Word`:

```
var word = await db.Words
                   .Include(wf => wf.WordForms)
                   .AsNoTracking()
                   .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

var output = word.WordForms.Select(wf => new
{
    WordId = wf.Word.WordId,
    CategoryId = wf.Word.CategoryId,
    WordFormId = wf.WordFormId,
    PosId = wf.PosId,
    Definition = wf.Definition
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your really good answer.  If I wanted to pick just one category would I just do that with a .Where(w => w.CategoryId = 123) after db.Words?

Comment: Yes, that's the way.

Comment: Sorry, is after the `Include`

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the `WordForm` to start with

```
    from wf in db.WordForms
    //your where conditions even on wf.Word
    select new 
    {
       WordId = wf.Word.WordId,
       CateogoryId = wf.Word.CategoryId,
       WordFormId  = wf.WordFormId,
       PosId = wf.PosId,
       Definition = wf.Definition
    }
```